# Gradle version 1.6 is required. Current version is 1.8-20130730220035+0000

Tags: android, android-studio

Just updated Android-Studio to version **0.2.7** an now I get the error message from the title:

[image: error message]

In the log window there is link to the grade setup:

[image: configuration dialogue]

No matter which option I use the error message stays the same.

I deleted my `~/.gradle` directory and projects `**/.gradle` directories.

It seems that nothing helps.

Nitpick: compile on the command-line using `\opt\gradle\1.6\bin\gradle.bat build` works fine.

Comment: I get the same error after upgrading from Gradle 1.7 to 1.8 after having already been on Android Studio 0.2.7

Comment: As [suggested by jfsso](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18689803/356895): Run `gradle wrapper` in the root directory of your project to generate an updated version of the wrapper files: `gradle-wrapper.jar` and `gradle-wrapper.properties`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I managed to fix my project through some combination of invalidating Android Studio cache, deleting `.idea` and `.gradle` directories and `.iml` files, restarting Studio, and reimporting the project:

[image: Invalidate Cache] [image: confirm]

on Mac OSX using Homebrew, `brew install gradle` then pick local gradle distribution and point to `/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/1.7/libexec` for gradle home:
[image: local distribution]

Comment: As of now brew will install version 1.8 by default, which also causes the Askers error.

Comment: I paste /usr/local/Cellar/gradle/2.0/ to gradle home and it is wrong, yes need paste /usr/local/Cellar/gradle/2.0/libexec! Thanks @vinc3m1! to best answer!

Answer (score 12):

1. Go to Preferences > Project Settings > Gradle and choose "Use gradle wrapper" instead of the bundled option
2. Open your `gradle-wrapper.properties` and change the `distributionUrl` to use 1.7 if it is not already (mine was 1.6), i.e. `distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.7-bin.zip`

Comment: I got the same **Gradle version 1.6 is required. Current version is 1.8.** error. I tried changing the distribuitionUrl from `distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-bin.zip` to `distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.7-bin.zip` am getting a different error **Gradle version 1.8 is required. Current version is 1.7. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/upandian/Library/Caches/AndroidStudioPreview/compile-server/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-1.8-all.zip**

Answer (score 8):

You do not want to manage gradle at a system level, it is better handled per project. Android Studio projects already setup gradle wrapper handling when creating new projects but if you have an older one you can add the same file that Android Studio does. Think of this as an gradle bootstrap file that will download the correct gradle version per project. You can also read up on [Gradle Wrapper](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) and generate a shell script called gradlew that will provide gradle-free bootstrapping.

In `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` in your project directory make sure you have:

```
#
#Tue Oct 08 13:40:54 CEST 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.7-bin.zip
```

Then when you go into Gradle you can set it to use the gradle wrapper. This is the default when creating new projects in Android Studio.

There are at least three approaches to migration or adding Gradle properly and using the new project structure Google and Android Studio has introduced.

- Create a new project and copy over the code
- Export from Eclipse to Gradle (deprecated)
- Import code into Android Studio (recommended)
- Try to manually get everything in order by creating the correct gradle files and reorganizing the project.

For now I'm copying the files over to a new project until the tools get a bit better.

Answer (score 2):

We have two computers, one of which gave that same message after upgrading to Android Studio 0.2.7.  We noticed that the computer which could still build had Gradle installed independently of Android Studio.

Installing Gradle 1.6 downloaded from the Gradle web site fixed this issue on the computer that wouldn't build.

Answer (score 2):

My fix was basically what Abe did but I wanted to give a bit more explanation:

Download gradle 1.6 from the [gradle website](http://www.gradle.org/downloads)

Extract somewhere on your pc/mac

Open up android studio, go to Preferences -> Gradle (left panel) -> and chooose Local gradle distribution. 
Point Gradle home to the location where you extracted gradle.

This fixed the issue for me. Using the gradle wrapper and the bundled gradle distribution both failed

Answer (score 2):

In my case, i updated gradle to the latest version (1.8) and then changed the gradle.build files (for my project and for the libraries i was using) like these:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.1+'
}
```

The Synchronize files and Refresh/Invalidate cache. This seems to solve the problem. I think that Gradle in order to determine the minimum required version just reads the above value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to get my project working:

1. Installed Gradle 1.7 on my OS (OS X users can use brew for this)
2. Added this to my `local.properties` file: `sdk.dir=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk`
3. Created gradle wrappers with `gradle wrapper` command.
4. Chose "Use gradle wrapper (recommended)" option in Android Studio.