# Upgraded android studio and get build error with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

After upgrading to version 0.27 I get this error when trying to build and run my project:

```
Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'BeerPortfolioPro'.
> Gradle version 1.6 is required. Current version is 1.8-20130730220035+0000
```

My gradle file begins with this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
```

I tried changing it to 1.6 and 1.8 and neither fixed the problem.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659145/gradle-version-1-6-is-required-current-version-is-1-8-201307302200350000 for some solutions.

Comment: That helped but now I cant get the app on my phone.... new stack question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have wrong version of Gradle. Try to downgrade Gradle and check if Gradle 1.6 is set in Android Studio preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to:

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+
```